# Cant accelerate past 80km

Tags: tucson

While driving my 2009 tucson I began experiencing a loss of power my vehicle didint cut off that time but the afternoon after I began my drive home and accelerated to 100km and abs soon as I eased my foot off the gas ...the engine died...first the rpm completely fell and the engine light came on and as soon as I slowed to about 50km the battery and ebreak lit up and steering became increasingly difficult .?I pulled to the curb put it in park and restarted... it started but the engine light stayed on and came off after about 12h or so

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Pull the engine codes as a start likely clues